# Convert one (long) column into multiple (short) columns of unequal lengths

Tags: linux, awk, sed, text-formatting

I have a file with one column of data (i.e., one data value per line). 
I interpret these data as multiple *data **sets**;*
the data sets are separated by one or more `NA` lines. 
Note that the data sets are not the same length. 
I want to convert this to a multi-column format
in which each data set is in a column
(in the same order as they appear in the input file).

For example,
I have following file (in reality, the file contains much more data):

```
NA
4
3
5
7
8
3
NA
NA
NA
3
4
5
2
NA
2 
7
4
6
9
NA
```

My expected output is the following:

```
4 3 2
3 4 7
5 5 4
7 2 6
8 . 9
3
```

The point between 8 and 9 is not really needed, but could also be replaced by a space.

Comment: Please specify 1. if the NA lines have to be discarded (why mention them then?) 2. what made you decide to stop the first column and start the next one at the 7th number, why not the 6th one (and you would not need a dot)

Comment: 1) yes Na have to be discarded. That is how my file looks like

Comment: 2) always stop a column when Na appears

Comment: Are the values always a single digit?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `awk` to split each group of data (where those are between `NA` lines) into separate files and skipping `NA` lines, then `paste` them together.

```
awk '/^NA$/ && !NA{N++; NA=1; next} !/^NA$/{print >"file"N; NA=0}
    END{system("paste file*")}' inile.txt
```

The `NA` flag is used to create files in sequencial order, we could use below instead.

```
awk '/^NA$/{N++; next} !/^NA$/{print >"file"N}
    END{system("paste file*")}' inile.txt
```

The output is:

```
4 3 2
3 4 7
5 5 4
7 2 6
8   9
3
```

Answer (score 1):

That output format doesn't make sense to me. I don't think it's going to be practical at all.

Anyway, just write it per line, then transpose (or better, leave it per line):

```
tr '\n' ' ' < example | tr 'N' '\n' | sed 's/^A //; /^$/d'
```

gives

```
4 3 5 7 8 3 
3 4 5 2 
2 7 4 6 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Transposing in the shell is a pain in the butt. Here's a short answer with Perl that requires [Array::Transpose::Ragged](https://metacpan.org/pod/Array::Transpose::Ragged) from CPAN

```
perl -MArray::Transpose::Ragged=transpose_ragged -lnE '
        if (/NA/) { $n++; next }      # next row
        push @{$data[$n]}, $_;        # creating the 2D matrix of data
    } END {
        say join "\t", @$_ for transpose_ragged [grep {defined} @data];
' file
```

Here's another approach: the pipeline before `gawk` is essentially the same as @n.caillou's answer, the awk code does the transposing

```
paste -sd " " file | sed 's/NA/\n/g' | sed '/^ *$/d' | gawk '
    {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) data[FNR][i] = $i
        if (NF > max) max = NF
    }
    END {
        for (i=1; i<=max; i++) {
            for (j=1; j<=NR; j++) printf "%s\t", data[j][i]
            print ""
        }
    }
'
```

Uses GNU awk for multi-dimensional arrays

Answer (score 0):

The [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) version 1.1.1 is needed. In the version 1.0.7 it doesn't work correctly.

```
#!/bin/bash

tr '\n' ' ' < input.txt |
sed 's/\s*NA\s*/\n/g;' |
sed '/^$/d'  |
datamash --no-strict --filler="." -W -t' ' transpose
```

**Explanation**

1. `tr '\n' ' ' < input.txt` - replaces all newlines to spaces. In other words, join all lines to the one line.
2. `sed 's/\s*NA\s*/\n/g;'` - replaces all 'NA' and adjacent spaces to the newline. That is, it splits the big line to few separate lines, each is the future column, written horizontally.
3. `sed '/^$/d'` - removes all blank lines.
4. `datamash --no-strict --filler="." -W -t' ' transpose`

   - `--no-strict` - allow lines with varying number of fields
   - `--filler="."` - fill missing values with dot. It can be changed to the space.
   - `-W` - use whitespace (one or more spaces and/or tabs) for input field delimiters.
   - `-t' '` - use space instead of TAB as output field delimiter.
   - `transpose` - converts rows to columns.

**Input**

```
NA
4
3
5
7
8
3
NA
NA
NA
3
4
5
2
NA
2
7
4
6
9
NA
```

**Output**

```
4 3 2
3 4 7
5 5 4
7 2 6
8 . 9
3 . .
```